# In neo4j, does apoc.lock.nodes() last for an entire transaction?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I'm performing some operations in nodes that belong in a linked list in neo4j, this requires several separate queries. The linked list has a head node that I use to lock the list while I run these statements using the js driver's transaction.run() function.

My question is: does the lock I get when I run apoc.lock.nodes() in the first statement last the entire transaction or just for that first statement?

Answer (score 0):

Since `apoc.lock.*()` methods do nothing special rather than acquiring common locks, they are all released in the end of transactions:

https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/blob/3.5/src/main/java/apoc/lock/Lock.java

Behavior is no different from the one described in docs:

https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/3.5/transactions/#transactions-locking